# How to change the background image after animation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background image but not working:

The simple one works:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#img').css({'background-image':'url("image-path.png")'});
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYj6P/1/)

But this doesn't work as if it has css3 animation applied:

```
#img{
    animation: changeImage 1s;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation: changeImage 1s linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

[problem demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYj6P/4/)

Comment: please view this in chrome.

Comment: The animation works on load. What is the exact question here?

Comment: yes, but when clicked to button then the image should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between **animations** and **transitions** in CSS.

An animation defines a set of properties that change over time **including how they change and what they change to**.

A transition, on the other hand, just defines **how properties change**. Transitions do not change the properties themselves.

What you have done in your *problem demo* is define an animation, then expected it to behave like a transition.

If you put the **animation** css into its own class, you can then apply that class to the image and watch the animation happen:

**CSS**

```
#img.change{
  animation: changeImage 1s;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: changeImage 1s linear;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#img').addClass('change');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYj6P/7/)

Alternatively, you can define a **transition** on the background of the image, then update the image as you were before and the background should fade:

**CSS**:

```
#img{
    background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR6CRSAoE8I7AUbRwKXScakaTFWO0t_TvPPmW1aXyNTGeErtLuT4w');
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    transition: background 1s ease-in-out
}
```

Your javascript will still work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYj6P/8/)

Comment: animation is not working in your demo when you click to button it's animating but I wanted to change the background image after animation when clicked to button

Comment: Combine both approaches then.